# insert decimal type to clickhouse database , there have error of unexpected type string

Tags: go, clickhouse

I am a beginner, I don't understand why insert decimal type field "money", it echo "money (Decimal(18, 2)): unexpected type string"

[image]

```
func main() {

    dsn := "tcp://localhost.39:9000?database=test&read_timeout=10&write_timeout=20"
    db, err := gorm.Open(clickhouse.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
            SingularTable: true,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err.Error())
    }
    err = db.Create(&Orderinfo{
        Id:         uuid.New().String(),
        Money:     decimal.New(15001, -3),
        Vip:        "VIP0",
        CreateTime: time.Now().UnixMicro(),
    }).Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err.Error())
    }

}
```

```
create table if not exists test.orderinfo
(
  id String ,
  money Decimal64(2),
  vip  String,
  create_time Int64
  
) engine = MergeTree
partition by (create_time)
order by id;
```

Comment: import (
 "github.com/google/uuid"
 "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
 log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
 "gorm.io/gorm"
 "gorm.io/gorm/schema"
 "time"
 "gorm.io/driver/clickhouse"

)

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your decimal to string:

```golang
strconv.FormatFloat(decimalValue, 'f', -1, 64)
```

It works for me with library github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I found "gorm.io/driver/clickhouse" use the package clickhouse-go.
when I check the code in clickhouse-go, I found that clickhouse-go support decimal not well!
It will check the data type when data insert into database.If data type of col in db is decimal,the clickhouse-go packgae only accept int32,*int32,int64,*int64,float32,float64,*float32,*float64!
Gorm mapping decimal to string and Most db do it by this way.
So the problem occurs.
I found clickhouse-go/v2 support github.com/shopspring/decimal.